# No logro que en la matriz salgan los resultados que espero

Tags: c++, c, matrices, dev-c++

Como dice el título necesito que salgan ciertos valores pero sale 0, lo que quiero es que tengo un arreglo z y con los elementos de ese quiero por ejemplo llenar el primer renglón con el número del arreglo z elevado al número de columna en el que se va a ponr, este es el código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double z[' '], y[' '], e=0, m[' '][' ']={0};
int i, j c=0, n=0;

main()
{
        //Número de variables para la matriz
        printf("Interpolacion de Polinomio Unico\nIngresa el numero de pares\n");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        c=n+1;
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            printf("Ingrese el numero de z[%d]: \n", i+1);
            scanf("%lf", &z[i]);
            printf("Ingrese el numero de y[%d]: \n", i+1);
            scanf("%lf", &y[i]);
        }
        printf("\n|  x   |   y  |\n");
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            printf("| %lf | %lf |\n", z[i], y[i]);
        }
        //Ciclo para llenar la matriz
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            for(j=0; j<c; j++){
                m[i][j]=pow(z[i], j);
                if(j=c-1){
                    m[i][j]=y[i];
                }
            }
        }
        printf("    Matriz Inicial      \n\n");
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            for(j=0; j<c; j++){
                printf("%lf ", m[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n\n");
        }
        printf("\n\n\n");
        printf("Presione cualquier tecla para terminar\n\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Pero cuando lo ejecuto y pongo por ejemplo estos datos n=4; x={1,2,9,10}; y={7,8,5,11}

Sale así la matriz

1 0 0 0 7

1 0 0 0 8

1 0 0 0 5

1 0 0 0 11

No se porque sale así, debería salir así

1 1 1 1 7

1 2 4 8 8

1 9 81 729

1 10 100 1000 11

Perdón si no se termina de entender es la primera pregunta que hago aquí y este error no se porque sucede y se me dificulta explicarlo.

Comment: Por curiosidad ... ¿ Podrías indicarme donde has aprendido a declarar el tamaño de un *array* usando un `carácter literal` como valor numérico (`double z[' '], y[' '], e=0, m[' '][' ']={0};`) ? Me ha dejado **alucinado** en cuanto lo he visto O-O

Comment: Me han enseñado que es para que el arreglo no tenga un límite

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre decirte: cambia **URGENTEMENTE** de centro / academia / profesor.

Comment: El arreglo si que tiene un limite, el espacio vacío es un carácter ASCII con valor 32, es decir que tus arreglos tienen tamaño 32.El fallo esta en que estas haciendo una asignación en vez de una comparación al llenar la matriz, cambia `j=c-1` por `j==c-1` y te funcionará correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

creo que los 0 que aparecen es debidoa que el "if" que tienes dentro del
"//ciclo para llenar la matriz" esta asi:
A)
if(j=c-1)
y deberia ser:
B)
if(j==c-1)
puesto que asi como esta en A) en vez de evaluar una condicion esta asignando un valor a la variable "j" y pues eso explica el porque solo esta modificando la primera y ultima casilla en el caso de prueva que mencionas.